# When arranging numbers and letters in combinatorics, should one use multiplication or addition?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Let's say that we are given that a code is formed with 3 letters of alphabet followed by 3 digits from 0-9, and both can be repeated. When required to find the total number of combinations. Is it correct to 26*26*26*10*10*10=17576000 or should one use addition to say 26*26*26+10*10*10=18576 ? Which one is correct to use ? and would there be a case where we have to use the other ?

Comment: what does you intuition suggest?  what about a simple case of one number and one letter?

Comment: Multiplication. But in a small country, graduates in Arts get a $3$-letter code, and graduates in Science get a $3$-digit code. Then one adds.

Comment: @DougM Well for one number and one letter, it would be multiplication. What seems to confuse me is that it seems like the letters are strictly followed by numbers--as in maybe YYY000.... which must be wrong ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas could you please make another example for addition ?

Comment: @Dan: They are all the same. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then the number of elements in $A\cup B$ is the number of elements in $A$ plus the number of elements in $B$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I hear you. Could you recommend some good books for this chapter. I am still high school and it's a bit problematic for me.

Comment: It has been a while since I have chosen a text for this kind of material, so I have not kept up with the books. You will get over the "is it addition or mutliplication"  pretty quickly, it is just a matter of solving a few dozen problems.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, the codes are of the form "XXX###", where I'm using X to represent any possible letter, and # any possible digit. So "ABC123" is a valid code, but "123ABC" isn't.

For the first letter, there are 26 possible choices. Regardless of the first letter, there are also 26 possible choices for the second letter. So if the first letter is A, there are 26 possible second letters. If the first letter is B, there are 26 possible second letters. If the ... and so forth. Hence, for each of 26 separate cases, there are 26 possible second letters, which if we add that all up gives us 26*26 possibilities for the first two letters.

Extend that to the third letter, and the same thing holds. If the first two letters are AA, the third letter has 26 choices. If the first two letters are AB, the third letter has 26 choices. If the ... and so on to ZZ, hence for the letters there are 26*26*26 different selections.

For the numbers, is anything different? Well, there are only 10 possibilities for each of them, but other than that? Is there any combination of letters that *can't* be followed by a particular set of numbers? If not, then we can apply the same logic. And hence ...